# HOG in OpenCV for classification of entire images

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, classification

I understand that Histograms of Gradients in OpenCV are typically used on image patches in order to detect and classify objects in an image.

However, I would like to use HOG to build a feature vector that can be used to classify an entire image. Using the following:

```
std::vector<float> temp_FV_out;
cv::HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.compute(img_in, temp_FV_out);
```

gives very long feature vectors each of different lengths, due to the varying size of the image - larger images have more 64 x 128 windows, and each of these contributes to the feature vector's length.

How can I get OpenCV to give a short feature vector (about 5-20 bins) from each image, where the length of the feature vector remains constant regardless of the image's size? I would rather not use bag of words to build a dictionary of HOG 'words'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to normalize the image size - choose the smallest size you want to process,and resize the rest to this base size. You can also establish a small size as default (100x100, by example) You may need to crop them, if they do not have the same aspect ratio.

Next, you can select a number of features from your vector, based on various algorithms: PCA, decision trees, Ada boost, etc - which can help you extract the most significant values from your data.